# How to style a specific element inside a td in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Example: I want to style that element in my style.css file

```
  <table>
     <thead>...</thead>
     <tbody id="something">
        <tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="1">
           <td>Data 1</td>
           <td>Data 2</td>
           <td>Data 3</td>
           <td>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <a href="#">The element I want to style.</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="2">
           <td>Data 1</td>
           <td>Data 2</td>
           <td>Data 3</td>
           <td>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <a href="#">The element I want to style.</a>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>

   <table>
```

I want to style that element in my style.css file using css selectors

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example structure

```
.highlight_on_hover td a:nth-child(2)
```

would get it done.

```css
.highlight_on_hover td a:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="something">
    <tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="1">
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">The element I want to style.</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="2">
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
        <a href="#">The element I want to style.</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style the particular element by defining the class name or id to element.

```
<tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="1">
           <td>Data 1</td>
           <td>Data 2</td>
           <td>Data 3</td>
           <td>
                <a href="#" >Link</a>
                <a href="#" class="link">The element I want to style.</a>
           </td>
</tr>
```

style.css

```
  .link {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to style all `<td>` tag , add css

```
table td{ color:red; font-weight:bolder;}
```

*this css will style all your data in your table*

---

or if you want to style a spesific `<td>` element , try this

```
<table>
<tbody id="something">
        <tr class="highlight_on_hover" id="1">
           <td> <span style="color:red;"> Data 1 </span></td>
           <td>Data 2</td>
           <td>Data 3</td>
           <td>
                <a href="#">Link</a>
                <a href="#">The element I want to style.</a>
           </td>
</tbody> </table>
```

use `<span>` element to style a spesific element

**I hope this will help you**